# What's the meaning of "for it was" in this sentence: For it was brilliant weather

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, verbs, vocabulary, conjunctions

In The Fairy Tale of Father Brown by G. K. Chesterton, the city and state of Heiligwaldenstein, which was one of those toy kingdoms of which certain parts of the German Empire still consist, saying

> The German soldiers by the innumerable sentry-boxes looked strangely like German toys, and the clean-cut battlements of the castle, gilded by the sunshine, looked the more like the gilt gingerbread. **For it was** brilliant weather. The sky was as Prussian a blue as Potsdam itself could require, but it was yet more like that lavish and glowing use of the colour which a child extracts from a shilling paint-box.

What's the meaning of **for it was** here?

Comment: It means, roughly, "because", which is also a preposition in examples like yours.

Answer (score 1):

According to Collins Dictionary, it is a subordinating conjuction, which means 'because'. Look at the 11th point of https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for_1
.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "for" means "because" (see its use as a conjunction https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for It provides an explanation (weather) for why the "battlements of the castle [...] looked [...] like [...] gingerbread".

Comment: Thank you so much